# How to use libltdl on OS X in a Qt project

Tags: c++, macos, qt, libltdl

I try to use *libltdl* in Qt on *OSX*. I downloaded the library with *brew* and i can find it in `/usr/local/lib/libltdl.dylib` .

I link it in Qt Creator using the assistant and those lines were added to my *.pro*

```
macx: LIBS += -lltdl
```

The problem is when i use :

```
#include <ltdl.h>
```

the app doesn't compile and the following error appears :

```
fatal error: 'ltdl.h' file not found
#include <ltdl.h>
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: What is the path to the header, and what is the path to the file you're compiling? If you didn't [add the path to `INCLUDEPATH`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/third-party-libraries.html#source-code), you have to ensure the path is complete enough to find the header.

Comment: So far, you've only told the linker that you'd like to use that library. You haven't told the linker where to find it. You also didn't tell the compiler where to find the header file.